# rviz crash when adding Path or Map plugin

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz crash when adding Path or Map plugin: As soon as I set the topic in the property setting it crashes.
Running Indigo under Unbutu 14. Has anyone else run into this? I have a robot model in my world file.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot create GL vertex buffer in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::GLHardwareVertexBuffer at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 46)
[rqt_gui-6] process has died [pid 4466, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui __name:=rqt_gui __log:=/home/richard/.ros/log/96788b60-135c-11e4-aa17-28cfe95d78b1/rqt_gui-6.log].
log file: /home/richard/.ros/log/96788b60-135c-11e4-aa17-28cfe95d78b1/rqt_gui-6*.log
[rqt_gu
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187731/rviz-crash-when-adding-path-or-map-plugin/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run into this too. I opened this [bug ticket](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/96) on Github.
Unfortunately AFAIK there is no proper solution yet. You might confirm this bug on the Github tracker thread to increase visibility of that issue.

The current workaround for me is that I still use an older version of the `ros-indigo-rqt-gui-cpp` package without the breaking change.

```
rqt tags/0.2.13 works
rqt tags/0.2.14 crashes
```

---

Originally posted by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) with karma: 152 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-24**:
I chose to just launch it as a separate node that works even though it opens a new window. But now I can pass in a custom rviz config file.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-07-25**:
You mean you use the rviz standalone application (not via rqt)?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-25**:
yes .......